# Sending objects between viewcontrollers that are bundled with navigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have two viewcontrollers that are both bundled with navigationcontrollers. Im trying to send an object from one viewcontroller to the other. I use the code below in the didselectrow of the table:

```
UIViewController *serviceTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationServiceNews"];

    ((TableServiceNews*)serviceTable).service_ID = [ServiceID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight
        animations:nil onComplete:^{
        CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = serviceTable;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];
```

The identifier that im using (navigationServiceNews) points to the navigationcontroller that is bundled with the destination viewcontroller.

While using this identifier, the app crashes because obviously instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier returns a veiwcontroller not a navigationcontroller.

When i change the identifier to the ID of the destination viewcontroller,every works fine but i lose the navigationBar on the header which is very important to my project(it is the reason i decided to bundle the viewcontrollers with navigationcontroller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "navigationServiceNews" is the identifier you assigned to the navigation controller, then instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: will instantiate a navigation controller not a UIViewController, so that's not your problem. You problem is on the next line -- I assume that serviceID is a property on TableServiceNews not the navigation controller, so you need to get ahold of that controller using topViewController.

```
    UINavigationController *serviceTableNav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationServiceNews"];
    TableServiceNews *serviceTable = serviceTableNav.topViewController;

    serviceTable.service_ID = [ServiceID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight
            animations:nil onComplete:^{
            CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController = serviceTable;
            self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
            [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];
```

Comment: ok i understand the problem and your solution and i think it works but im not sure how to implement it in my code. I would really appreciate it if you could help me out here.

Comment: i tried this and it sends the object to the other view but im still losing the navigationbar at the header.

Comment: @RashidAsgari, You're going to have to describe your setup more fully. I have no idea what slidingViewController is, and where it fits in to the hierarchy. Also It seems wrong that self.slidingViewController.topViewController is serviceTable since we just said a couple of lines up that that is the top view controller of serviceTableNav.

Comment: I finally got it right! it shoould be self.slidingViewController.topViewController = serviceTableNav;
Thanks @rdelmar you are a life saver :)